# Query to check if column value appears more than once

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have a PostgreSQL query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("contract"."contract_id") "contract"."id"
FROM "contract_versions" "contract"
WHERE "contract"."client_id" = 1 
GROUP BY "contract"."contract_id", "contract"."id" 
ORDER BY "contract"."contract_id", "contract"."change_effective_date" DESC
```

I want to add something like if contract_id occurs more than once then change_effective_date >= now()

Dataset:

```
 id  | contract_id | client_id | change_effective_date 
-----+-------------+-----------+-----------------------
 100 |          10 |         1 | 2020-05-17 00:00:00
 200 |          10 |         1 | 2020-05-16 00:00:00
 300 |          10 |         1 | 2020-05-14 00:00:00
 400 |          20 |         1 | 2020-05-17 00:00:00
 500 |          30 |         1 | 2020-05-13 00:00:00
 600 |          30 |         1 | 2020-05-14 00:00:00
```

Expected result:

```
 id  | contract_id | client_id | change_effective_date 
-----+-------------+-----------+-----------------------
 200 |          10 |         1 | 2020-05-16 00:00:00
 400 |          20 |         1 | 2020-05-17 00:00:00
 600 |          30 |         1 | 2020-05-14 00:00:00
```

If the count of contract_id is more than 1, I want a row with change_effective_date less than or equals today

I tried using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON ("contract"."contract_id") "contract"."id", 
      COUNT("contract"."contract_id") AS cnt 
FROM "contract_versions" "contract" 
WHERE "contract"."client_id" = 1 AND 
CASE WHEN "cnt" > 1 THEN "contract"."change_effective_date" <= now() END 
GROUP BY "contract"."contract_id", "contract"."id" 
ORDER BY "contract"."contract_id", "contract"."change_effective_date" DESC
```

but its throwing an error `column "cnt" does not exist`

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have never seen `DISTINCT ON` combined with `GROUP BY`. It is possible (aggregate first, then pick rows from that aggregation result), but this is not what you are doing and it is not what you want either. You want the ranking applied by the `ORDER BY` clause for the `DISTINCT ON` to take the current date into account.

```
SELECT DISTINCT ON (contract_id) *
FROM contract_versions
WHERE client_id = 1
ORDER BY 
  contract_id,
  CASE WHEN change_effective_date <= CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END,
  change_effective_date DESC;
```

Demo: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=f709d18b23504dfaf9f586ace231be1d

Comment: Thanks, this worked. Can you please explain this line:
`CASE WHEN change_effective_date <= CURRENT_DATE THEN 1 ELSE 2 END`

Comment: Dates until today are ordered first (because we give them a sortkey 1, while the others get the sortkey 2. Thus we get 2020-05-16 before 2020-05-17 for instance in case a contract_id has rows both until today and in the future. After all, the sort order is just the ranking order for `DISTINCT ON` to pick its rows.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner . . . `DISTINCT ON` can be useful with `GROUP BY` as well.  Consider a query where you want to get something like the city in each state that has the most orders.

Comment: @Gordon Linoff: I agree. I just haven't seen it used before, but this may be due to using Oracle mainly. I am pretty sure I would have used it myself already, if PostgreSQL were my DBMS :-) Thank you for giving an example.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 problems in your queries:

1. In the first query you have:

> ERROR:  column "contract.change_effective_date" must appear in the
>   GROUP BY clause or be used in an aggregate function

2. In the second you cannot directly reference a column alias ("cnt") in the query: you can do this in another query that must reference the original query as derived table or inline view.

Here is something that could be a solution:

```
select * from contract_versions;
 id  | contract_id | client_id | change_effective_date 
-----+-------------+-----------+-----------------------
 100 |          10 |         1 | 2020-05-14 14:00:00
 100 |          10 |         1 | 2020-05-14 14:00:00
 100 |          10 |         1 | 2020-05-14 14:00:00
 100 |          20 |         1 | 2020-05-16 09:00:00
(4 rows)

Null display is "NULL".
SELECT DISTINCT ON (contract_id) contract_id,
       change_effective_date
FROM contract_versions contract 
WHERE client_id = 1 
GROUP BY contract_id, id, change_effective_date
ORDER BY contract_id, change_effective_date DESC;
 contract_id | change_effective_date 
-------------+-----------------------
          10 | 2020-05-14 14:00:00
          20 | 2020-05-16 09:00:00
(2 rows)

SELECT DISTINCT ON (contract_id) contract_id,
       COUNT(contract_id) AS cnt,
       change_effective_date
FROM contract_versions contract 
WHERE client_id = 1 
GROUP BY contract_id, id, change_effective_date
ORDER BY contract_id, change_effective_date DESC;
 contract_id | cnt | change_effective_date 
-------------+-----+-----------------------
          10 |   3 | 2020-05-14 14:00:00
          20 |   1 | 2020-05-16 09:00:00
(2 rows)

SELECT
contract_id,
CASE WHEN cnt > 1 THEN change_effective_date <= now() 
END 
FROM
(
  SELECT DISTINCT ON (contract_id) contract_id,
         COUNT(contract_id) AS cnt,
         change_effective_date
  FROM contract_versions contract 
  WHERE client_id = 1 
  GROUP BY contract_id, id, change_effective_date
  ORDER BY contract_id, change_effective_date DESC
) v;
 contract_id | case 
-------------+------
          10 | t
          20 | NULL
(2 rows)
```

Comment: put different dates in the change_effective_date where contract_id is 10. It's not giving the latest row rather it is just picking the first row it finds. I want to retrieve the rows with latest change_effective_date but distinct contract_id and if some contract_id appears more than once than change_effective_date <= now()

Comment: Please edit your question to add some intput data and the expected query result.

Answer (score 0):

With `row_number()` window function:

```
select t.id, t.contract_id, t.client_id, t.change_effective_date
from (
  select *,
    row_number() over (
      partition by contract_id
      order by (change_effective_date > now())::int, change_effective_date desc
    ) rn
  from contract_versions 
) t
where t.rn = 1 
order by t.id
```

It is not clear in your question, because your sample data contains only 1 `client_id`, if a `contract_id`'s value belongs to only one `client_id`.
If this is not the case, then you must change in the above query:

```
partition by contract_id
```

to:

```
partition by contract_id, client_id
```

See the [demo](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/c2RrByKttdxxgL8emDq1bW/2).
Results:

```
| id  | contract_id | client_id | change_effective_date    |
| --- | ----------- | --------- | ------------------------ |
| 200 | 10          | 1         | 2020-05-16 00:00:00.000  |
| 400 | 20          | 1         | 2020-05-17 00:00:00.000  |
| 600 | 30          | 1         | 2020-05-14 00:00:00.000  |
```

Comment: this one worked too thanks, but its more complicated.